# Creating a map with gmapping using kinect and fake odometry data

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the title speaks for itself, what I've done so far is creating this launchfile,
which seems to do everything right - at least "rostopic echo /scan" echos something.

```
<launch>
  <!-- kinect and frame ids -->

  <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch"/>

  <!-- openni manager -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="openni_manager" output="screen" respawn="true" args="manager"/>

  <!-- throttling -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="pointcloud_throttle" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudThrottle openni_manager">
    <param name="max_rate" value="2"/>
    <remap from="cloud_in" to="/camera/depth/points"/>
    <remap from="cloud_out" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>

  <!-- fake laser -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="kinect_laser" args="load pointcloud_to_laserscan/CloudToScan openni_manager">
    <param name="output_frame_id" value="/openni_depth_frame"/>
    <remap from="cloud" to="cloud_throttled"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

Furthermore I followed the instructions to create fake odometry data.
[found here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom)

This also seems to work....so I tried [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData), but all I get is "Waiting for map".

Please feel free to ask for further information, if needed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43718/creating-a-map-with-gmapping-using-kinect-and-fake-odometry-data/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Give [this](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam) a try. You don't need odometry for it.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-09-13**:
Maybe I should have mentioned that: The fake odometry data are just needed for tests - the robot I want to use publishes odometry data. Any ideas why my solution does not work?
thx